Linear transformation over frames of a video
Say we have a linear map give by a matrix, $R$. The linear map acts on a vector and takes it to another vector. Now, we'd like to apply the linear map not all at once, but gradually, over $n$ frames. So that we can see it in motion frame by frame and then convert that motion into a video.
I thought a good way to do this was to take the singular value decomposition of $R$. Then, we can raise the diagonal matrix in between to $\frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ is the number of frames in the video. This would give you $R^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Then, multiply the original vector by $R^{1/n}$ to get the first frame, $R^{\frac{2}{n}}$ to get the second frame and so on.
This makes some sense since, if we wanted to apply the linear map twice, we would multiply the vector by $R^2$. So, why not raise it to the power of $R^{\frac{1}{n}}$ when we want to apply it $\frac{1}{n}$ times?
And this seems to work great for rotation matrices. However, when I try it on matrices that involve reflections, this seems to break down. Consider for example the matrix below.
$$R = \begin{pmatrix}  
1 & 0 \\  
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
If we apply this to $(0,1)$, we get the vector $(0,-1)$.
If we do the singular value decomposition, we get
$$R = \begin{pmatrix}  
1 & 0 \\  
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  
1 & 0 \\  
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  
1 & 0 \\  
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$$.
Now let's say we want a video with $3$ frames. We get:
$$R^{\frac{1}{3}} = \begin{pmatrix}  
1 & 0 \\  
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  
1^{\frac{1}{3}} & 0 \\  
0 & 1^{\frac{1}{3}} 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  
1 & 0 \\  
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$$.
The only sensible thing seems to be to take the cube roots of unity for the central diagonal matrix and perhaps take the real part. However, even that breaks apart since the second and third cube roots have the same real part. So it would seem like no progress was made between frames $2$ and $3$.
Why does this method of breaking the action of linear map into frames, that works so well for rotation matrices, break down so miserably for such reflection matrices?
And is there some universal way to break a linear map into frames that will work for all of them?

Isn't the diagonalization of your reflection matrix: $I R I$, since $R$ is already diagonal?  In this case, your taking the roots $1^{{1}/{3}}$ and $(-1)^{{1}/{3}}$ which is just $1$ and $-1$.  The visualization would show the reflection bounce back and forth, and eventually land on the final reflection.  Reflections are period 2, so not sure there is a great visualization of a reflection inside a video clip?

I was hoping there might be a way to take the complex roots and get a smooth transition that way?

Interesting.  Also, it would be cool to see the y-axis flip over in slow motion in a video.  Some special effects could be added ... flipping the xy-plane using a spatula like a flapjack.
